# The type 'Servicios.WS1' is ambiguous

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Acabo de desarrollar un Web Service que será consumido por una App hecha en Xamarin.

Cuando lo pruebo por el localhost no hay problema, pero cuando lo publico en la web me da el siguiente error:

> The type 'Servicios.WS1' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly '...\bin\Servicios.DLL' or from assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\proyectoprueba\c21c2264\96decd05\App_Code.oa1uqjc4.DLL'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Servicios.dll está copiada en la carpeta bin y es de ahí donde debería llamar el tipo Servicios.WS1 pero por algún motivo que desconozco, no puedo hacer que funcione.

Alguien podría ayudarme?!!

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Has probado a eliminarlo de la carpeta `..\bin\Servicios.Dll`?

Comment: @Pikoh si, he probado y sigue sin funcionar... inclusive la dll la publiqué desde el Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, pude corregirlo con la info de este link

http://www.herlitz.nu/2011/08/26/the-type-is-ambiguous-it-could-come-from-assembly-or-from-assembly-please-specify-the-assembly-explicitly-in-the-type-name/